# Is there any way to merge two tables into one while every columns are same only the FK is two different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to merge two table into one while every columns are same only the FK is two different table?

Table #1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reports1]
(
    [Rep_ID] [INT] NULL,
    [Rep_Context] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Rep_MemberID] [INT] NULL,
    [Rep_AdminitstratorID] [INT] NULL
)
```

Table #2:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reports2]
(
    [Rep_ID] [INT] NULL,
    [Rep_Context] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Rep_RestaurantID] [INT] NULL,
    [Rep_AdminitstratorID] [INT] NULL
)
```

`Rep_ID` is the PK of both tables.

`Rep_RestaurantID` and `Rep_MemberID` are the PK of the two tables, is there any good way to merge two table into one?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here. Why are there two separate tables, and what would be the problem using a simple insert...select statement?

Comment: Are you looking to resolve conflicts? I.e. what if RestaurantID and MemberID both have rows with the same value? Do you care about Rep_ID being duplicated?

Comment: You mean "Rep_RestaurantID and Rep_MemberID are the **FK** of the two tables"?

Comment: It will be good to post sample data and expected result and you have already posted schema which is good.

Comment: When you say "merge into one" are you asking about how to write a SELECT query to query the data, or are you seeking advice on how to better design the tables so you can get rid of the two existing tables and have the same data in just one table?

Comment: Yes, "Rep_RestaurantID and Rep_MemberID are the FK of the two tables", sorry for the typing mistake. 
And what I looking for is not merge by simple SELECT query, I want to have a way to only have one table.

Answer (score 1):

use union

```
select Rep_ID,Rep_Context,Rep_MemberID,Rep_AdminitstratorID from Reports1
union
select Rep_ID,Rep_Context,Rep_MemberID,Rep_AdminitstratorID from Reports2
```